# Performance concern accessing $refs in Vue JS to pull data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

**Overview:**

I'm building a hybrid application in Nuxt JS 2.9.2 which pulls data via GET requests using Axios. A user has the ability (through a form wizard) to add an object into an array, each object includes X amount of fields, and a unique slug which is accessed through the URL, e.g: `http://localhost:3000/#/url/slug`

The problem is, my array could contain as many as 10+ objects, each object consisting of maybe 5+ key/value pairs.

**Problem:**

My biggest issue right now, is with performance, and best practice. I need to be able to access an individual object's set of data from within my `methods, created, mounted` etc.

And right now, I also need to be able to access the individual index of each item to display data.

So, from within my `pages/url/_url.vue` file, I'm looping over each object, which is fetched from a computed property through local storage, and then only displaying the specific object if the slug, through the URL matches the slug that is gotten from the object.

But I understand, at load, all elements are rendered on the DOM, and then removed one by one that don't match, and I'm wondering if there's a different way of getting the data without using my current method of using Vue JS Refs?

I also need to be able to access the value of a given object's key, and by outputting it's value onto the screen and using refs to get it, is at the moment my only way?

```
<template>
  <div class="has-safe-area-y fill-height" id="pullto">
    <div v-for="(url, index) in urlsList" :key="url.id" v-if="slug === url.slug">
      <div class="is-hidden">
        <div ref="getId">{{ index }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef1">{{ urlsList[index].item }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef2">{{ urlsList[index].anotherItem }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef3">{{ urlsList[index].foo }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef4">{{ urlsList[index].bar }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef5">{{ urlsList[index].apple }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef6">{{ urlsList[index].cake }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef7">{{ urlsList[index].laravel }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef8">{{ urlsList[index].vue }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef9">{{ urlsList[index].test }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef10">{{ urlsList[index].notification }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef11">{{ urlsList[index].item2 }}</div>
        <div ref="getRef12">{{ urlsList[index].item3 }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      slug: this.$route.params.url,
      urlsList: []
    }
  },
  methods: {

    // My methods reference the refs, e.g:
    // this.$refs.getRef2[0].innerText

  }
}
</script>
```

**What's the actual problem?**

Am I doing the right approach here in accessing an object's value from within the mounted, and my methods by using Vue JS refs, and what other options are there?

Comment: I don't follow the complete explanation if what's going on here. If the contents of `urlsList` is available as `data` or a prop, then you should not need refs to access it. You should really only need refs for weird corner cases like programmatically focusing an input or working with an external library that's manipulating your DOM (jquery plugin, etc.).

Comment: It would help to see how any of the methods are called. A common mistake that people make is they don't realize a template can call a method with arguments (which can then be used to identify the data).

Answer (score 0):

One thing would be to move the loop into a template instead of the div. I think they're all rendering and then being removed because you're looping and using a conditional on the same element.

```
<template v-for="(url, index) in urlsList>
    <div :key="url.id" v-if="slug === url.slug">
    ...
</template>
```

But, since you're wanting to reference the item that is displayed, I would move the loop into a function and only have the one that's displayed in the template.

```
<div>
  <div class="is-hidden">
    <div>{{ index }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.item }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.anotherItem }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.foo }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.bar }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.apple }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.cake }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.laravel }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.vue }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.test }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.notification }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.item2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ display.item3 }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
...
computed: {
    index() {
        for (url, index) in this.urlsList {
            if (url.slug === this.slug) {
                return index;
            }
        }
    },
    display() {
        return this.urlsList[this.index];
    }
}
...
methods {
    // this.display.anotherItem
}
```

I haven't tried it, so don't know if the code works as-is, but that's the basic idea.

If it's possible for there to be more than one to display, change index() and display() to return lists. Same idea, though.